# How retrive the value from ui::inputSelect?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

I have a Lightning component with a list of the Account from Salesforce:

```
    <ui:inputSelect label="Account" class="form-control" aura:id="selectAccount"  onSelectChange="{!c.onSelectChange}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
            <ui:inputSelectOption value="{!account.Id}" label="{!account.Name}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>
```

It works right. How to retrive the Id of the selected account option?
I'm expecting on the onSelectChange callback to see the params, but with:

```
onSelectChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.getParams());
}
```

I get this output:

```
app.js:14666 Event {source: Component, $eventDef$: EventDef, $eventDispatcher$: undefined, $eventName$: "change", $params$: Object…}
app.js:14667 Object {}
```

While I'm expecting to see at least the name of the Account..

Any advice?

Comment: input select option uder aurta:iteration , i am not able to access the value by component.get. but the same can be retrieved if the put the input select outside the aura:iteration. .... Is it work like that ? I get lightning error '$handleSave [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined]"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few potential errors in the code. `onSelectChange` should be `change`, and `value` should be `text`.

Please try this:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>

<ui:inputSelect aura:id="o" label="Contacts" change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!contact.Id}" label="{!contact.Name}" />
   </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

And then you can use the `component.find().get()` pattern to retrieve the Id.

```
onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var selected = component.find("o").get("v.value");
    console.log(selected);
},

doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Your own implementation for loading records
    helper.getContacts(component); 
}
```

Here are a few docs related to `ui:inputSelect`:

- [ui:inputSelect](http://demo.auraframework.org/auradocs/reference.app#reference?descriptor=ui:inputSelect&defType=component)
- [Create a Component for Salesforce1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one_demo.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I think that even if this stack exchange wth people (like you) that know the aura framework very well is a great tool.. documentation lacks a lot.

Comment: Spoke with my developers and they mentioned that you don't need array indexing anymore as of Spring '15. I updated the answer here and I'll be adding this to the ui:inputSelect docs as well. https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/commit/65849c3ae8e948bfad24c4c669c673ecba3d6913